# How to parse the following JSON array?

Tags: java, json

I am having hard time to figure it out how to parse the following JSON (Dynamic):

```
[{
"existingData": [
  0,
  0
],
"guestId": {
  "__type": "Pointer",
  "objectId": "EB1rr6Lqtp"
},
"listingAddressGeopoint": {
  "__type": "GeoPoint",
  "latitude": 36.002702,
  "longitude": -78.90682099999998
},
"numberOfListingImages": 1,
"preferredGender": "\"Female\"",
"urlOfListingBeds": [
  "https://xyz.image0.jpg"
],
"urlOfPrimaryImage": null,
"createdAt": "2015-09-09T14:54:36.139Z",
"updatedAt": "2015-09-15T14:46:41.988Z",
"user": {
  "createdAt": "2015-09-09T14:54:34.841Z",
  "updatedAt": "2015-09-09T14:54:34.841Z"
   }
}]
```

The problem is sometime data starts `previuosData` not from `existingData`. How can I get the array of `urlOfListingBeds` in list of Some object?

## Model class

```
public class Image {
    public List<String> urlOfListingBeds;
}
```

## Edit-1

I tried to access it by following code but it is throwing an errror

```
 for (int i = 0; i < rjson.size(); i++) {
        rjson.getAsJsonObject(i);
    }
```

where as rjson is `JsonArray`

Comment: whatever u have tried, plz shar with us.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java)

Comment: *The problem is sometime data starts previuosData not from existingData* since you don't need that data, it shouldn't be  a problem at all

Comment: @TimCastelijns I am not able to figure out how to put iteration in jsonArray

Comment: Use a for loop for iterations

Comment: @TimCastelijns can you please look at the Edit-1 section

Comment: @Def which json library are you using ?

Comment: @SubhrajyotiMajumder com.google.gson.JsonArray;

Comment: I can't use jsonschema2pojo.org due to big json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the JsonArray from json object by calling `getAsJsonArray()`. Create a iterator by calling JsonArray#iterator, and iterate over each JsonElement, and get `JsonObject` by calling `JsonElement#getAsJsonObject()`.

Once you have `JsonObject`, you will find the `urlOfListingBeds`.

Code:

```
JsonArray array= rjson.getAsJsonArray();
Iterator iterator = array.iterator();
List<String> urlOfListingBeds = new ArrayList<String>();
while(iterator.hasNext()){
    JsonElement jsonElement = (JsonElement)iterator.next();
    JsonObject jsonObject = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject();
    JsonArray urlOfListingBed = jsonObject.getAsJsonArray("urlOfListingBeds");
    if(urlOfListingBed!=null){
        Iterator iter = urlOfListingBed.iterator();
        while(iter.hasNext()){
            JsonElement jsonElementChild = (JsonElement)iter.next();
            if(jsonElementChild!=null)
                urlOfListingBeds.add(jsonElement.getAsString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it is throwing an error i.e. `JsonElement` is already defined. So I changed the `jsonElement` to `jsonELementChild` but after that http://pastebin.com/Hf5DxxPk @ `urlOfListingBeds.add(jsonElementChild.getAsString());`